# Как перенаправить запрос из папки в корень с помощью .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess

Помогите пожалуйста перенаправить запросы из папки в корень сайта.

Ситуация следующая, на том же домене, но в запрещенной от индексирования папке выгружалась "тестовая" версия сайта (в папку /new/). Но Яндекс просто проигнорировал запреты в robots и проиндексировал папку, а после удаления этой папки в Webmaster пишет об увеличении страниц с кодом 404.

Сейчас .htaccess выглядит следующим образом:

```
#Rewrite everything to https
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Как я могу перенаправить все запросы поступающие по адресу www.site.com/new/ на аналогичные страницы (с тем же наименованием и расширением), но в корне сайта?

В рамках эксперимента дополнил .htaccess следующим правилом:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)new(.*)$ $1/$2 [QSA,L,R=301,NC]
```

Переадрессация происходит, но в адресе возникает двойной слэш и элементы страницы отображаются не корректно.
Вот такого вида ссылка получается: www.site.com//index.html

Comment: У вас "в рамках эксперимента", в группы также попадают слеши, а вы его потом снова устанавливаете. Попробуйте например `^(.*)new(.*)$` заменить на `^(.*)new\/+(.*)$` как в этом примере https://regex101.com/r/eRacj7/1

Comment: чуть исправил `^(.*)\/+new\/+(.*)$` -> `$1/$2` ,https://regex101.com/r/FEcp8q/1

Comment: Благодарю!  

Первый вариант сработал как надо !!!, а вот второй, исправленный - нет.  
Спасибо за элегантное решение!

Comment: во втором варианте я видимо ошибся, помойму туда попадает строка после домена, т.е не `www.site.com/new/index.html`, а только `new/index.html`, поэтому там и нет `(.*)\/+`, т.е. по идее у вас должен сработать и такой вариант `^new\/+(.*)$` -> `/$1`, можете на досуге попробовать.

Comment: Попробовал последний вариант - он вызвал ошибку 500.
Остановлюсь на втором варианте, который безукоризненно работает.
Большое спасибо!